# How to remove blank line created in the XML file after deleting a particular atrribute

Tags: c++, xml, xml-parsing, xerces, domparser

I have a XML document, for example

```
<document>
    <attribute id = 1 />
    <attribute id = 2 />
    <attribute id = 3 />
    <attribute id = 4 />
    <attribute id = 5 />
    <attribute id = 6 />
</document>
```

I am using DOM parser to parse the XML file in my **C++** code.
I am deleting a particular attribute, for eg id = 3.

Using the API's from Xerces library, I delete the attribute,
but i am getting a blank line in the place where i deleted the 
attribute.

Deleting is done as follows. I will remove the required attribute from given file and copy
the remaining contents to a temp file but a blank line created.

```
<document>
    <attribute id = 1 />
    <attribute id = 2 />

    <attribute id = 4 />
    <attribute id = 5 />
    <attribute id = 6 />
</document>
```

I need the output as follows, the blank line should not be present in the file
after deleting

```
<document>
    <attribute id = 1 />
    <attribute id = 2 />
    <attribute id = 4 />
    <attribute id = 5 />
    <attribute id = 6 />
</document>
```

Comment: It could be just the way you're printing it out. The blank line probably doesn't exist in the actual document. How are you trying to parse/print the XML? Also, I think your notion of an XML attribute vs XML element is a bit fuzzy. The `<attribute id="3"/>` is actually an XML element.

Answer (score 1):

Use this method to achieve desired ...

```
private static void formatWSDL(Document doc, String path) {
    try {
        OutputFormat format = new OutputFormat(doc);
        format.setIndenting(true);
        XMLSerializer serializer = new XMLSerializer(new FileOutputStream(new File(path)), format);
        serializer.serialize(doc.getDocumentElement());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I convert my document to **Document** type?